# Print Diff of two text files

Tags: applications, software-recommendation, macos

I'd like to compare two text files **on a paper**. Which app should I use to print a diff of two files?

I know several apps to show diff on a screen and usually use *MacVim*. However, MacVim seems not have a feature to print diff side by side.

Comment: http://www.kaleidoscopeapp.com perhaps worth a look (sorry, I don't have time to check if it includes printing, but it has many other features...)

Answer (score 1):

I thought [perhaps BBEdit](http://www.barebones.com/products/bbedit/featuressearch.html) might have what you want. Under the Search menu, there is a Find Differences command, wherein the text files can be selected.

However, the result shows the file contents side-by-side, on screen. When printed, the output is merely a list of which lines did not match.

As a workaround, might I suggest the following:

1. Perform the comparison using whatever software works for you.
2. Get a screen capture (i.e., bitmap) of each page of side-by-side text.
3. Print the bitmaps.

It will be somewhat rough, but you'll (probably) have the printed sheets of line comparisons that you need.

Answer (score 1):

There are sites that will do diff for you.

Do you use GitHub?  I think their site's Diff displays are [quite nice](https://github.com/braziljs/js-the-right-way/commit/2ea21aae6bccda62462c97973226acb7b41e488f), and seem to print just as nicely.

Otherwise a google search turn up a few other sites that offer this service, here's one that seems to have decent print support:

https://www.diffchecker.com/

Of course using this method you have to not be too worried about the confidentiality of your document, or have a great deal of trust in the service provider!